# Why jQuery progress bar is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a Google hosted jQuery script ..right?
So I do not need to download anything ..I guess.
but then when I load the page why do not it shows any thing 
What is the trick am I missing here?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery UI Progress Bar</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery UI -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js">  </script>

<script>
$(function () {
//call progress bar constructor           
$("#container").progressbar({ value: 50 });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/5qPqh/ Try clearing your cache.

Comment: Your script runs perfectly. Why do you say that it isn't? Have a look at your code at jsfidle --> http://jsfiddle.net/x6gn9/

Comment: I think, your answer is `Ctrl+F5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By any chance are you testing from your local machine with "file:" URLs?

If so, you can't use URLs in the form:

```
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"
```

because that is the equivalent of:

```
src="file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"
```

And thus your scripts won't be found.

During development, set them to `http:`:

```
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"
```

And switch them back when you go to production (if you want).

Comment: rechmach, please "accept" this answer by clicking the big check/tick next to the answer.  Normally I don't post reminders about this, but I see that you have received answers to four questions, and you haven't accepted any of them.

Comment: I did not know how to accept the answer. I tried it , has it been accepted?